# Strange AttributeError in django

Tags: python, django

In my model file I have class extra .

That has property lease that calculates lease based on other model LeaseExtra

```
class Extra(CommonInfo):
        number = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
        max_occupants = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
        floor = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
        _lease = None


        def _get_total(self):


            from lease.models import Lease
            from conditions.models import LeaseExtra

            le_dict = LeaseExtra.objects.filter(extra_id=self.id, is_active = True ).aggregate(Max('id'))

            if le_dict:
                lease =  le_dict.lease
            else:  
                lease =  0
            self._lease = lease


class LeaseExtra(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    extra = models.ForeignKey(Extra,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    lease = models.ForeignKey(Lease,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_included = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Why I am getting error in this model class ?

> Exception Value:
>
> > 'dict' object has no attribute 'lease'

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\rent_unit_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\rent_unit_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\src\unit\views.py" in extra_available_list
  163.     extra_list = [obj for obj in extra_list if ( (obj.lease)==0)]
File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\src\unit\models.py" in lease
  182.             self._get_total()
File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\src\unit\models.py" in _get_total
  160.             lease =  le_dict.lease

Exception Type: AttributeError at /unit/list/extra/available/
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lease'
```

Comment: From the docs: `aggregate() is a terminal clause for a QuerySet that, when invoked, returns a dictionary of name-value pairs. ` link to the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: If `le_dict` is a dictionary, I wouldn't expect it to have a lease attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

le_dict is initialised as a queryset because of the use of the 'filter' function. I.e. it is not a single object instance.

Therefore, it does not make sense to reference the 'lease' attribute as a queryset of many LeaseExtra instances may have been returned.

If you want to reference 'lease' of a specific model instance, you can do:

```
le_dict = LeaseExtra.objects.get(pk=some_id)
```

The get() method requires that you use a unique identifier such as a primary key to perform your query.